# How to hide JavaScript files from the Chrome Developer Tools, in Next.js?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, next.js13

I have a Next.js project. My concern is, the utils/components are easily visible throught the Chrome Developer Tools, as can be seen here:

[image]

How can I hide them? More importantly, is it safe to have them easily accessible?

Comment: If the code is sensitive, I think it is best to have it executed and handled on the server instead of the client-side.

Answer (score 2):

It is not practical to hide JavaScript files from the developer tools if you are serving a client-side rendered application. By nature, JavaScript is executed on the client's browser, and the files need to be accessible for the application to run.
You can, however, disable source maps for your production build. This will make it harder (but not impossible) to read the code, as it won't be formatted or mapped to the original source. However, keep in mind that the code will still be visible; it will just be minified and harder to follow

```
// next.config.js

module.exports = {
  productionBrowserSourceMaps: false,
  // other configurations...
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You should probably learn about minimization and obfuscation.
This will not completely hide your code, but it will make it hard to read.

There are a lot of different tools for this, just make sure the one you use, is compatible with the version of Javascript you are using, much likely ES6+.

You can learn about Javascript obfuscation on this page: 
[***Javascript Obfuscation Tool***](https://obfuscator.io/)

Comment: I find that people who get to the point where they interact with obfuscated code, will not be phased by it. This used to be useful for reducing file sizers, but today, this is less of a concern. If anything, obfuscated code is _longer_ and costs more bytes to send, with absolutely 0 advantage.

Comment: I've been working with this all my life, it all depends on your stack. 
When you develop, you don't work with obfuscated code, you only do it when deploying the product. 
Almost every JS framework does it nowadays. So I don't agree with your statement.

Comment: Oh I have been working too, and give me a good _reason_ to obfuscate other that "everybody does it". But that's neither here nor there, do as you please, but doing it just gives you an illusion of more safety.

Comment: I didn't say you are wrong, I don't agree that obfuscation is not useful, and it's been phased out. 

Yes, obfuscation can make the code slightly worse, but you are not forced to use all of the obfuscation techniques. 
You should know that Minification exists partially because of obfuscation and Minification it's currently in use in many frameworks.

It's also important to split the development environment from production.
You shouldn't program with obfuscated or minified code, but when deploying this is a must for most apps.

Comment: This is not the place, but that's, like, just _your opinion_, man. And you come across as if people who don;t obfuscate don't production right, and that's just, well, not true. Your reasons aren't well argued, they're just "popular opinion" in the "hardcore dev" community.

Comment: No, it is not my opinion. At least have some respect and give the benefit of the doubt even if you think you are sure of something.
Just take a look at the scripts on every webpage you visit. Including this one.
Check how many scripts are minified, and/or obfuscated.
It's that simple!
Some pages even randomize CSS classes, just to avoid crawlers picking text in specific elements.  Just because you don't like it, or you don't use it, doesn't mean it isn't the standard everywhere else.

Comment: The argument of popularity again. It's your _shared_ opinion, then. Shared with people who are convinced by the argument of popularity. Great argument, that. (Now if you could actually obfuscate in JS, that would be a good argument, bit you can't)